# Not able to fetch posts using CPT categories

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have registered a CPT in WordPress theme. I can able to fetch posts in the loop by post_type but when I am trying to get posts by category_name. It is not giving me results.

```
add_action( 'init', 'achivement', 0 );

function achivement() {
register_post_type( 'achivement', array(
    'label'             => __( 'Achivement', 'achivement-free' ),
    'description'       => __( 'Achivement custom post type.', 'achivement-free' ),
    'public'            => false,
    'has_archive'       => false,
    'publicaly_queryable' => false,
    'query_var'         => false,
    'show_ui'           => true,
    'show_in_menu'      => true,
    'menu_icon'         => 'dashicons-networking',
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
    'hierarchical'      => true,
    'menu_position'     => 20,
    'supports'          => array(
        'title',
        'editor',
    ),
    'capability_type'   => 'post',
    'labels'            => array(
        'name'               => __( 'Achivements', 'achivement-free' ),
        'singular_name'      => __( 'Achivement', 'achivement-free' ),
        'menu_name'          => __( 'Achivement', 'achivement-free' ),
        'all_items'          => __( 'Achivements', 'achivement-free' ),
        'add_new'            => __( 'Add Achivement', 'achivement-free' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add Achivement', 'achivement-free' ),
        'edit'               => __( 'Edit', 'achivement-free' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Achivement', 'achivement-free' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'New Achivement', 'achivement-free' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'Search Achivements', 'achivement-free' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'No Achivements found', 'achivement-free' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Achivements found in Trash', 'achivement-free' ),
        'parent'             => __( 'Parent Achivements', 'achivement-free' ),
    )
) );

register_taxonomy(
    'achivement-category',
    'achivement',
    array(
        'label' => __( 'Category' ),
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'achivement-category' ),
        'hierarchical' => true,
    )
);
}
```

and here is the loop which I am writing to fetch the posts by category_name in WordPress.

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'post_type'         => 'achivement',
    'order' => 'ASC',
));
if( $posts ):
foreach( $posts as $post ): 
    setup_postdata( $post );
    var_dump(get_the_category());
 endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();
endif;
```

I know maybe there will be a silly minor mistake but I am not able to get it. Please let me know if you can find that mistake. I will be very thankful.

Thanks

**Got a working query from below answer. I am pasting that here for others.**

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'achivement',
'posts_per_page' => 500,
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'strike',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => array( 'strike-1' ),
    ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) : 
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
        echo get_the_title().'<br />';
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
else :
    _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' );
endif;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, don't use `'posts_per_page' => -1,`, this has serious impact on the query speed.

Second of all, just use `WP_Query` and specify the taxonomy parameter like described here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters

Something like this should work

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'achivement',
    'posts_per_page' => 500,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'achivement-category',
            'field'    => 'name',
        ),
    ),
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @dingo_d. Got it a bit late but it is working now. I am updating my query in question with the working query for others.